# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined when trying to register user for website node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I seem to have messed up one of my promises (I think) in a javascript function that is supposed to register a user. I have included the post request and the actual function itself.

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    dataServiceAuth.registerUser(req.body).then(() => {
        res.render("register", {successMessage: "User created"});
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.render("register", {errorMessage: err, user: req.body.user});
    });
});



module.exports.registerUser = function (userData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (userData.password != userData.password2) {
            reject("Passwords do not match");
        }
        else {
            let newUser = new User(userData);

            newUser.save((err) => {
                resolve();
            }).catch((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.code == 11000) {
                        reject('User Name already taken');
                    }
                    else {
                        reject('There was an error creating the user: ${err}');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Seems like `newUser.save` is not returning something `catch`able, but `newUser.save` was not posted in your code.

Comment: Check if `newUser.save` is a Node style callback which is passed a falsey value for the `err` parameter when the operation succeeded,  or a non-falsey value (includes non zero numbers) if an error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

If `newUser.save` can return a promise, you definitely shouldn’t be passing a callback to it, or even using the `Promise` constructor at all. If you really want to reject with strings, the way to implement that would be by transforming rejections from `newUser.save()` with `.catch` into new rejections by returning them, and returning the resulting promise from `registerUser`:

```
module.exports.registerUser = function (userData) {
    if (userData.password != userData.password2) {
        return Promise.reject("Passwords do not match");
    }

    let newUser = new User(userData);

    return newUser.save().catch((err) => {
        if (err.code == 11000) {
            return Promise.reject('User Name already taken');
        }
        else {
            return Promise.reject('There was an error creating the user: ${err}');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Awesome looks fixed everything and it looks a lot cleaner as well.